# What is the purpose of setSupportActionBar? What does it do?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

If there is a toolbar, it is usually passed into setSupportActionBar(). Why?

Answer (score 1):

As per [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar)

> A Toolbar is a generalization of action bars for use within application layouts. While an action bar is traditionally part of an Activity's opaque window decor controlled by the framework, a Toolbar may be placed at any arbitrary level of nesting within a view hierarchy. An application may choose to designate a Toolbar as the action bar for an Activity using the setActionBar() method.

But in simple ways, this is a way of telling the Activity that you are interested in using the features related to Toolbar. It will delegate the functionalities related to your defined toolbar. It helps activity to understand the many of the requirements some of them mentioned below.

- 1) Setting menu options
- 2) Setting Navigation drawer
- 3) Setting common Toolbar
- 4) Setting back button on the top left
- 5) Using an icon for brand identification
- 6) Setting a common title or subtitle
- 7) And many more

If you don't mention for these functionalities by telling the activity using `setSupportActionBar` then you have to create all this by your self and support them back to the older version. With Toolbar it comes free and you have to just tell a activity to use it will take of supporting different functionalities itself.

Answer (score 1):

if **you want to apply your custom toolbar** instead of default toolbar then to set toolbar into that specific screen/activity you must be use **setSupportActionBar()** along with your toolbar. ;)